# Removing all content of specific folder

Tags: android, camera, delete-file

I am trying to remove all content of my device folder on hardware back press but it is not happening?

Here is what I am trying:

```
     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

         deleteFileFromDirectory();
         finish();


    }



 public void deleteFileFromDirectory()
    {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");


        if (mediaStorageDir.exists()) {

            isdeleted = mediaFile.delete();
            System.out.println("File deleted :" +isdeleted);//gives false
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Directory not exist");
    }
```

Documentation says it must be empty ... so what should I do?

Comment: Aren't you trying to delete a folder?

Comment: Yeah i am trying to delete a folder! @yygyt

Comment: CapDroid's answer seems to solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your path contain file then you can delete but your path contain folder then this folder must be empty, so first of you have to delete all files from folder and delete particular folder.

Here is sample code.

```
public void DeleteRecursive(String strPath) {

    File fileOrDirectory = new File(strPath);

    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()){
        for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles())
            DeleteRecursive(child.getPath());
        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }else{

        fileOrDirectory.delete();
    }
}
```

just call this method and pass your sdcard path in parameter.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"MyCameraApp";

DeleteRecursive(path);
```